# Testing out ADX calculator

Tags: algorithmic-trading, indicator

I'm trying to program an ADX calculator in python, however I don't know if it is correct since I'm still a bit shaky on the financial side of things. I haven't found an ADX calculator online (surprisingly) so I can't compare it.

Should the following datasets generate the following ADX-values?

[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] --> 100

[10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1] --> 100

[2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512] --> 100

[5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5] --> 0

[1,2,3,3,2,1,1,2,3,3,2,1,1,2,3,3,2,1,1,2,3] --> 94.50548937857359

Could anyone with sufficient knowledge tell me if something seems off?

Comment: Does anyone know? Is this section of stackexchange dead?

Comment: Hi user18398, welcome to Quant.SE! No this section is not dead, but implementation of technical indicators is not on-topic here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP is attempting to implement technical analysis indicators, which is not pertinent to quant finance.